# Set value on datepicker

Tags: php, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a php variable which holds a selected date.

```
$newDate='07/04/2016';
```

And I want to set this date on  jQuery datepicker.
Can anyone please suggest a way to show `$newDate` instead of `new Date()` in

```
$("#datetimepickerFrom").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initializing a datepicker, you'd use the defaultDate option:

```
$("#datetimepickerFrom").datepicker({
    defaultDate: '<?php echo $newDate; ?>'
});
```

when changing the date later, you'd use setDate method:

```
$("#datetimepickerFrom").datepicker();
  // more code
$("#datetimepickerFrom").datepicker('setDate', '<?php echo $newDate; ?>');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXyLn/2/)

Comment: Thank you sir .Now i got it.

Answer (score 3):

You can just render your input with value already there and initialize the datepicker.

So in your backend you can render the input like this:

```
<input id="datetimepickerFrom" type="text" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($newDate) ?>"/>
```

And then simply initialize the datepicker in JS:

```
$("#datetimepickerFrom").datepicker();
```

Here's an [example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zecs-kj84).